# Are there queues between WebFilters

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am planning to use webflux to create a set of micro-services. Each service has a set of processing stages - a set of webfilters for pre-processing, a filter/stage to do some IO (which could become very slow), and a set of filters to do post processing. Each post procession filter need result of the IO operation to do its work. How does this work under the hood? Does the framework automatically trigger filters when results of the proceeding filter is available?

More information
Lets say I have a pipeline of filters. First filter does a remote API call - which may be slow. Second filter uses results of this API call. In a event loop based asynchronous processing pipeline, this would be modeled using one or more queues and a thread pool. Incoming requests would be put in to the queue and will be picked up by a worker thread. As the first step of the pipeline is doing the API call, this thread would do the API call and return immediately without waiting for the result. When result is received, it will be placed in the queue again and will be picked up by a worker thread and dispatched to the second filter which can use the result of the API call. Without a framework, we will setup queues, threads, message handlers in proper way so that at runtime above sequence of events happen. I just wanted to understand how this work in webflux.

Comment: I don't really understand the question; could you a a code snippet to illustrate what you're trying to achieve with WebFilter, and what should be the expected result?

Comment: @BrianClozel I have updated my question. Please have a look.